# System.Media.SoundPlayer Selective Playing

Tags: c#, soundplayer

I have a small application, the intent being that when a user presses a key a few things happen

1. Creates a new instance of an object for recording the keystroke
2. Checks a dictionary, grabs an instance of a System.Media.Soundplayer class
3. Modifies the backcolor of a section on the screen
4. Plays, async, the .wav file in the SoundPlayer

The Dictionary and SoundPlayer instances are instantiated when the form is loaded, and all the SoundPlayer instances synchronously Load() the .wav files prior to being added to the dictionary.

The form's KeyDown event looks something like this:

```
//do stuff up here, get the type, etc etc
//players is Dictionary<EnumFoo, SoundPlayer>

SoundPlayer sound = players[type];
sound.Play();

this.KeyUp += (sUp, eUp) =>
{
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    foo.Duration = endTime - startTime;
    sound.Stop();
    this.resetColors();
};
```

Here's my problem: It only appears to play the shorter sounds. Some are up to ~30 seconds in length, and others are less than 5. If I put a breakpoint anywhere after the SoundPlayer is instantiated, then even the long sounds play correctly.

I was considering using a ThreadPool and queuing the items up, but that option has its own set of ramifications.

Any ideas? I've never had to mess around with any of the media classes before.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, just realized why this was happening. Kind of a 3 step answer

1. A poor assumption that while I was holding the key down, only one KeyDown event was being fired. That is not accurate. It will fire multiple times.
2. I was pointed to the wrong audio files, which had a section of silence to preface the noise.
3. A long day and bad testing. The code itself is fine (at least, workable for the throwaway app I need it for) it was just poor testing on my part.